# Angular2 access another components methods without loading its template with @ViewChild

Tags: methods, angular, components, viewchild

I am trying to access a child components method with @ViewChild, and it works, but I am forced to load its template as well, which I don't want to do, because that also forces that child components `OnInit, AfterViewInit` and other system functions to run.

I want them to run only when I call this child component in a different scenario, but I want to access this childs custom methods on demand in AppComponent.

**So how do I do it?**

This is a plunker which depicts the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/FT6GTJ8mmUnyFxJAPbGV

You can see that dashboards test() function is called, thats what I **want**, however, its ngOnInit function is also initialized, which I **don't want**.

`template: <h1>AppComponent</h1><my-dashboard></my-dashboard>`

I though it was pretty obvious to remove `<my-dashboard></my-dashboard>` from AppComponent template, to not load dashboards template, but then I get error that dashboard itself is not defined (you can see the error if u remove `<my-dashboard></my-dashboard>` and run the plunker again) even though I have included it through import statement.

What am I missing?

**EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

So, in the end, you have to use a service to store reusable data/functions to work without a hick up.

Comment: What do you mean by that "but I am forced to load its template as well, which I don't want to do,". Without a template there is no component and there is no method to call.

Comment: Can't a component exist without a template? Even if it can't, can't I load only its class and call it's methods without also loading its template?

Comment: "I am forced to" because if I don't include the template, it will throw error.

Comment: You can call it's class but then it's only a class but not a component. A component can't exist (being instantiated) without a template and without being added to the DOM. If you don't want a template then create a directive. A directive is a component without a template.

Comment: You can use directive which doesnt have template.

Comment: Ok, sound logic. Is it possible to define a directive without telling him its selector? Because I don't want to attach it to an element, I don't want to see it anywhere in html. I just want to load it through @ViewChild and access its methods.

Comment: @Starwave `@ViewChild` can only find stuff inside your template.. Why do you want to use `@ViewChild` specifically?

Comment: `To get access to a component and its methods, we can use the @ViewChild annotation.`
I simply saw this in a guide and I thought this with be the defacto way of doing it. People above mentioned, that directives serve for this kinda purpose, so I'm trying to build a directive now. But I don't understand why I have to provide it a selector, why does it want to be attached to a dom element?

Comment: Seems like Directives are used to manipulate DOM, which I don't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you would want this, but you can try and use the `Component` as a provider. Although i fail to see how this can fall under the, "if it looks stupid, but it works, it ain't stupid", rule.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <h1>AppComponent</h1>
    `,
    providers: [DashboardComponent]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dashboardComponent: DashboardComponent){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dashboardComponent.test();
    }

}
```

[**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3QAM4dgtctxsMSDr0nHz?p=preview)

Another way I assume, could be to simply initiate a new class instance, this would result in something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <h1>AppComponent</h1>
    `
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public dashboardComponent: DashboardComponent = new DashboardComponent();

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dashboardComponent.test();
    }
}
```

[**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OodFgbboBXZvCG1LCH8w?p=preview)

But again I fail to see why you would want to do something like this. **Apparently there is logic in your component which shouldn't be there**

Comment: Both your ways do what I wanted. Thank you. My reason is this: Since dashboard is going to be my goTo component (this is gona be a 1 page app), I am going to define and keep all the functions that are associated with dashboard, like getting a user-set settings for custom component load in dashboard, or functions that are going to be used throughout the project, like recursiveArraySearch()... And in components where I will need these functions, I will simply call `DashboardComponent` either in a way you described or a directive way.

Comment: A better way would be to create a `DashboardService` which you can inject into the `DashboardComponent` as well as anywhere else.. but that's just my 5 cents :)

Comment: Damn it, you are right. I see now, your first approach is basically injecting a service, but instead of service it's a component without @Injectable decorator. And there are some weird problems when I am running a custom function that is defined in another component, but that's a problem with dynamic component loading, which is another story. So anyway, thank you, service is the way to go here :)